# Java: How to force a new SSL handshake with URL.openConnection()?

Tags: java

Client makes multiple calls with aURL.openConnection(), where URL represents a HTTPS address, to send data to the server. From Wireshark capture, it appears that only one SSL handshake is performed for the first send. How can I force a new SSL handshake on each send?

Comment: Why you need to make handshake on each send. As I know there is one handshake for a session. Server sends certificate to client, client save verify and save them, then data exchange starts.

Comment: Because for one of these sends, the client needs to authenticate itself with a client certificate.

Comment: I can only suggest to google with "java two Way SSL Authentication", there are many similar questions on stack about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way I found was to manually set the "Connection: Closed" Request Header.